# Why is my application only compatible with 14 devices on google play?

Tags: java, android

I am editing an App code. Only the front.

I am facing with the problem that the application runs over any device in debug mode, but, once I upload to google play the application is just comptible with 14 devices. ¿14? ¿Really?. I dont understand. It is very weird.

This is what is google showing me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFU0S.jpg

This all I have declared app use in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This is de app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app.name"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 68
        versionName "v2.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'aars'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: '../core/libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile project(':core')
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.51.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.1.0'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4-preferencefragment:1.0.0@aar'
}
```

IDK if there is another place where could be limiting the devices.

IDK if it is a peace af code doing this. The first time I am facing it.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
As you can see in the pic, the platform only refers to x86_64.  iDK if this is the problem. If it is the case, any idea how to solve it? please?

Answer (score 0):

As of 9/10/2017 and this answer will be outdated super fast, your app is not targeting the latest API, try targeting the API 26 Android O.

Change these and rebuild to the latest API 26 and update the dependencies

```
compileSdkVersion

buildToolsVersion 

targetSdkVersion
```

Comment: An api greater than 23 implies managing permissions in the application. At times I do not try to update the app, I want to make it to be used on many devices. Usually, if you use api 22 then api 23 will run the application as api 22. This can not be the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Right now Google supports the SDK on 14+ minimum SDK.So,it is generally preferriable to make youa apps minimum SDK to 14.Many of the apps SDK is functional and better for that minimum SDK value

Comment: This is not the case. Google supports api 14+ but anyway it should work even if I put api 10. I tried it out of curiosity and it did not work. Thank you anyway